# Azure SQL Database/Project Online - reporting on data sources in power bi, is it multiplexing?

Tags: sql-server, azure, powerbi, multiplexing

I'm trying to get some clarity on what is/isn't multiplexing and documents from microsoft on the matter aren't entirely clear for my use case [link to multiplexing docs](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://download.microsoft.com/download/3/D/4/3D42BDC2-6725-4B29-B75A-A5B04179958B/Licensing_Brief_PLT_Multiplexing.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwjTkIjb0Mb4AhVQa8AKHcjZCkQQFnoECBQQAQ&usg=AOvVaw3gw-_Xq_tmHyjobWm9n2Nj) Essentially I would like to report on data held in MS Project Online within Power BI, either directly using an OData feed or indirectly by managing this data in an Azure SQL database.  Would folk that purely need to view the summarised data in Power BI need a MS Project Online Licence?

In an alternate (data created in the Azure SQL Database or Microsoft SQL Server instance)/same scenario would the viewers also need a SQL licence?

This could lead to a situation where strategy planners could not see high level summary data without both a Project and SQL Server licence...surely this isn't correct am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

No, they users only need the relevant PBI license to see the PBI reports. If the report consumes data from SQL or Project Online, the report users do not need licenses for those.